# How can you make psql process idempotent in ansible?

Tags: postgresql, ansible, psql

I have a process which runs a `psql` process in `ansible`

```
- name: Run psql to pull in initial config data
  become_method: sudo
  become: yes
  become_user: postgres
  shell: psql -U postgres -w eclaim < /opt/eclaim_revamp/sql_scripts/{{ item }}.sql
  with_items:
    - initial_config
    - initial_sql_script
    - tmp_hrms
```

This task runs all the time. How do I make this idempotent ?

Comment: How can anyone tell? It depends solely on the script contents. You need to create pre-run checks (most likely a separate script for each of the three) and run the real scripts only if conditions returned by pre-checks are not met.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the only way is to wrap your sql-script into shell scripts and make checks.
Just as an example (I know there is `postgresql_user` module, but this is an example):

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $(psql postgres -tAc "SELECT 'found' FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname='{{ user }}'" | grep found) ]]; then
  echo "User exists"
else
  psql -c "CREATE USER {{ user }} LOGIN ENCRYPTED PASSWORD '{{ password }}';" > /dev/null
  echo "User created"
fi
```

And in your playbook:

```
- name: Run psql
  shell: createuser.sh
  register: result
  changed_when: "'User created' in result.stdout"
```

Comment: 1) non-idempotent 2) command line is not an asible way 3) but it works...

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to write up a script that queries the database to check it's status. This script should not be able to change anything, and should be set up as it's own task, using `changed_when: false` and printing some intelligent output. Register that output with `register: result`

Your existing task which makes all of your changes should have a conditional `when: result.stdout contains <some string>` so that it only runs if the first task finds that the database is not in the correct state.

A better solution would be to only use the provided Postgres modules for this setup, but without knowing what is in your .sql scripts, I can't know if that's possible.